# Haskell - How to extract TimeOfDay and DayOfWeek from ZonedTime

Tags: haskell

I am looking at the [time](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.8.0.3/docs/Data-Time-LocalTime.html#g:2) module and I want something like this:

```
import Data.Time.LocalTime

timeOfDayAndDayOfWeek :: ZonedTime -> (TimeOfDay, DayOfWeek)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Hope this reaches you in time to tell you when’s the new year. Have a happy one!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
import Data.Time.LocalTime
  (ZonedTime, TimeOfDay, getZonedTime, localDay, localTimeOfDay,
   zonedTimeToLocalTime)
import Data.Time.Calendar.WeekDate (toWeekDate)

-- toWeekDate numbers the days 1 for Monday to 7 for Sunday.
data DayOfWeek = Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

instance Enum DayOfWeek where
  toEnum 0 = Sunday
  toEnum 1 = Monday
  toEnum 2 = Tuesday
  toEnum 3 = Wednesday
  toEnum 4 = Thursday
  toEnum 5 = Friday
  toEnum 6 = Saturday
  toEnum 7 = Sunday -- Yes, twice.
  toEnum n = toEnum (n `mod` 7)

  fromEnum Monday = 1
  fromEnum Tuesday = 2
  fromEnum Wednesday = 3
  fromEnum Thursday = 4
  fromEnum Friday = 5
  fromEnum Saturday = 6
  fromEnum Sunday = 7

timeOfDayAndDayOfWeek :: ZonedTime -> (TimeOfDay, DayOfWeek)
timeOfDayAndDayOfWeek zt = let
    lt = zonedTimeToLocalTime zt
    day = localDay lt
    (_, _, weekDayNumber) = toWeekDate day
    dow = toEnum weekDayNumber
    tod = localTimeOfDay lt
  in
    (tod, dow)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  zt <- getZonedTime
  let (tod, dow) = timeOfDayAndDayOfWeek zt
  print tod
  print dow
```

You might prefer this version with a wrapper function instead of boilerplate, suggested by 4castle.  (Especially if you’d have to use more than one mapping from integers to the `Enum`.)

```
import Data.Time.LocalTime
  (ZonedTime, TimeOfDay, getZonedTime, localDay, localTimeOfDay,
   zonedTimeToLocalTime)
import Data.Time.Calendar.WeekDate (toWeekDate)

data DayOfWeek = Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday
  deriving (Enum, Eq, Read, Show)

-- toWeekDate numbers the days 1 for Monday to 7 for Sunday.
weekDateToDayOfWeek :: (Integer, Int, Int) -> DayOfWeek
weekDateToDayOfWeek (_, _, d) = toEnum (d-1)

timeOfDayAndDayOfWeek :: ZonedTime -> (TimeOfDay, DayOfWeek)
timeOfDayAndDayOfWeek zt = let
    lt = zonedTimeToLocalTime zt
    dow = (weekDateToDayOfWeek . toWeekDate . localDay) lt
    tod = localTimeOfDay lt
  in
    (tod, dow)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  zt <- getZonedTime
  let (tod, dow) = timeOfDayAndDayOfWeek zt
  print tod
  print dow
```

Comment: You can use `deriving (Enum)` to avoid writing that boilerplate code. Just subtract one from the result of `toWeekDate`.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. `toWeekDate` returns  7, not 0.

Comment: You can use `toEnum (weekDayNumber - 1)` to avoid writing that custom `Enum` instance.

Comment: Then I couldn’t pass the result to `toEnum`.

Comment: @4castle On second thought, I added a second example that uses a wrapper instead of boilerplate.

Comment: By the way, there’s also the package `Data.Dates` for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can go from `ZonedTime` to `LocalTime` to `Day`.

With `Day` you can use https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.3/docs/Data-Time-Calendar.html#t:DayOfWeek to get a `DayOfWeek` enum.

And use `localTimeOfDay` to go from `LocalTime` to `TimeOfDay`.